# Extending the PDP routes in spartacus?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

May I know how to implement this custom route in spartacus ?
`product/:productCode/:name/order-form`

I tried implementing this in my custom `order-form-routes.module.ts`
But it doesn't seem to recognize this config as it throws a Page Not Found error.

```
ConfigModule.withConfig({
  routing: {
    routes: {
      orderForm: {
        paths: ['product/:code/:name/order-form'],
        paramsMapping: { code: 'code', name: 'name' },
      },
    },
  },
}),
```

Comment: Is it a product page or a content page? If a content page, please see https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/adding-and-customizing-routes/#how-to-add-content-page-with-dynamic-params . If a product page, please use `:productCode` instead of `:code` (because PDP are recognized only by the existence of the `:prodcutCode` param - by convention). Then drop your `paramsMapping` for `code`. By the way... `paramsMapping` for `name` is redundant in your example and can be dropped anyway.

Comment: Its a ContentPage.. so I have tried your suggestion.  

But I can only load this custom route 
`/order-form/:productCode/:name` while I cannot seem to make the required `/product/:productCode/:name/order-form` work. 

Is it because, the URL is expecting to load a Product Page, instead of a Content Page?  I get a 404 Page Not Found error for the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

considering @Platonn's suggestion: 
This config made it work:

```
RouterModule.forChild([
  {
    path: 'product/:code/:name/order-form',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard, CmsPageGuard],
    component: PageLayoutComponent,
    data: { pageLabel: '/order-form' },
  },
]),
```